# Logic app nested forloop error The workflow run action 'Response' has type 'Response' that could not be nested under an action of type 'foreach'

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I Have simple logic app which call HTTP and process data.

After adding this forloop i'm facing an issue with below error -

```
The workflow run action 'Response' has type 'Response' that could not be nested under an action of type 'foreach'.
```

Why unable to use response in nested for loop.

After adding all code into main for loop it is throwing this error.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for this is simple  jn a two way http request response type of logic app, you can only send one response for a request. If suppose that logic app allowed you to send response in a for each loop, it then would mean that each time the flow enters the loop, then logic app would send a response.this in theory is not possible any client which initiates a request to a httpend point closes the connection once a favorable  response has been received. This is the reason you cannot put the response shape in for each loop

Comment: ohh i got your point but in that case i need to put response outside main loop... but it depends on condition again hmmm

Comment: how can i manage that outside loop please check the diagram above for response

Comment: What condition do you need to send different responses  for? Generally when I have to send certain responses based on a condition, I initialize a variable of type boolean at top and change its state inside the loop.when you exit the loop, just check the value of variable in the if or a switch statement and send the response

Comment: got you like we do in our c# code the similar way i have implemented in logic app too works fine now :) thanks